# Disable Firefox's builtin page search

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I want to disable the page search built into Firefox when I use Vimperator or Pentadactyl. I'm in the habit of hitting cmd-f (this is on OS X) to open Firefox's builtin page search but with Vimperator or Pentadactyl active it's a nuisance to close Firefox's builtin page search since Esc keystrokes are intercepted. I want to break my habit of using Firefox's page search and use the vim-style incremental search instead.

How can I prevent cmd-f from opening Firefox's builtin page search? I would also be fine with automatically closing the search bar after focus leaves it.

I know I can temporarily disable the interception of Esc but doing so requires quite a few keystrokes.

Even as I type this, the Firefox search bar is open, mocking me with a stale search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this may work in pentadactyl

`:map <M-f> <Nop>`